# R: Multiple Linear Regression with a specific range of variables

Tags: r, lm

It appears simple, but I don't know how to code it in R.
I have a dataframe (df) with ~100 variables, and I would like to do a multiple regression between the response which is my First variable (Y) and the variables 25 to 60 as regressors. The problem is that I don't  want to write each variable name like:

```
lm(Y~var25+var26+.......var60, data=df)
```

I would like to use something like [, 25:60] to select a complete range. I have tried it but doesn't works:

```
test <- lm(Y~df[, 25:60], data=df)
summary(test)
```

some idea?

Answer (score 8):

You could `subset` the dataset by selecting only those columns, and then do the `lm`.

```
lm(Y~., data=df1[c(1,25:60)])
```

Suppose, if you need `var25` to `var60` and if the data is ordered by column names

```
lm(Y~., data=df1[c(1,26:61)])
```

Or another option would be to use `paste` to create the formula

```
lm(paste("Y ~", paste(paste0('var', 25:60), collapse="+")), data=df1)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:80, 20*101, replace=TRUE),
   ncol=101, dimnames=list(NULL, c('Y', paste0('var', 1:100)))))
```

Comment: I think the `subset=` only applies to cases, not columns.

Comment: @thelatemail: Not so:  `subset(df1, select=c(1,26:60))`  ... `subset` has both a subset(rows) and a select(columns) option.

Comment: @BondedDust - I think you're confusing `?subset` with `subset=` in `?lm`

Comment: I may be misconstruing the point of your comment (which at the moment doesn't match up with anything in the question), but I don't believe I am confusing the arguments of the `subset` function.